# If $a^2+ab+bc+ca<0$, show that $a^2<b^2+c^2$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

*question*

Let the real numbers $a,b,c$:

a) If $a^2+ab+bc+ca<0$, show that $a^2<b^2+c^2$

b) If $b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca<0$, show that $a^2>b^2+c^2$.

*idea*

The first thing that came into my mind is the fact that we can demonstrate by AM-GM that

> $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$

which basically means that

> $b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca-a^2$

Maybe we can decrease this inequality from $a^2+ab+bc+ca<0$.

I don't know what to do forward. Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: Hint for the first: $(a+b)(a+c) < 0 $. So either $ c < -a < b$ or $ b < - a < c $. Now, consider where $0$ is in the inequality chain, and show that $ a^2 < \max (b^2, c^2)$.

Comment: Hint for the second: $(a+b+c) ^2 \geq 0$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you so much for your hint! I don't really understand why showing that $a^2$ is smaller than the max of those numbers is going to help us.

Comment: a) $a^2+a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca<b^2+c^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $(a+b+c)^2\ge 0$ helps as commented by Calvin Lin and Bob Dobbs.

a)
$$\begin{align}a^2&\le a^2+\underbrace{(a+b+c)^2}_{\ge 0}
\\\\&=2a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca
\\\\&=b^2+c^2+\underbrace{2(a^2+ab+bc+ca)}_{\lt 0}
\\\\&\lt b^2+c^2\end{align}$$

b)
$$\begin{align}b^2+c^2&\le b^2+c^2+\underbrace{(a+b+c)^2}_{\ge 0}
\\\\&=a^2+2b^2+2c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca
\\\\&=a^2+\underbrace{2(b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)}_{\lt 0}
\\\\&\lt a^2\end{align}$$

Comment: Rhnk you so much for your answer! I will give yu the bounty!!

Answer (score 1):

a) We have $(a+b)(a+c)<0.$

Let $a+b>0$. So $a+c<0$ and we need to prove that $(a-b)(a+b)<c^2,$ which is true for $a-b<0.$

But for $a-b\geq0$ we obtain $a>0$ and since $a+c<0$ we obtain $c<0$ and $$a^2<(-c)^2=c^2\leq b^2+c^2.$$